# Having trouble converting .NET generics lists to other generic lists

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I'm trying to model up a `lastminute.com.au` clone. When I try and create a collection of `IProductSearchServices`, I get all weird errors about (I'm guessing) variance vs covariance, etc.

*I've thought that I can any concrete type (to a collection) if any of the concrete types implement the same interface AND the collection is strongly typed to that same interface.*

Here's the code I'm trying to do.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Expected: 3 services in this list.
    var productServices = CreateProductServices();

    // Return all Hotel services.
    // Expected: 2 items in this list.
    var hotelServices = productServices.OfType<??????>();

    // for each hotel service, call SearchAsync.
    // wait for all the finish before continuing....

    Console.WriteLine("Found {0} products.", ....);
}

// Full code found in gist....
```

and this is my main error message:

[image]

And here is the [full repo code in a Gist](https://gist.github.com/PureKrome/10565421).

So what is the problem?

1. Trying to add 3 search services to a collection.
2. Given that list, I'm not sure how I can say: Give me all the hotel services, so I can then `SearchAsync` on them.

NOTE: I don't want to use `dynamic`, etc. I want to try and do this as a strongly typed collection, etc.

Comment: One of the problems here is that `Task<T>` is a class, not an interface. Covariance is only possible on interfaces, and as a result it is not true that `Task<Derived>` can be converted to `Task<Base>`. You can work around this by using [`IObservable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377.aspx) instead of `Task`, which is covariant, and offers similar functionality. Also, `IList` is not covariant, so you can use `IEnumerable` instead.

Comment: The big problem however, is `TSearchOptions`, which is _contravariant_. It is not true that `IProductSearchService<T, HotelSearchOptions>` can be assigned to `IProductSearchService<T, ISearchOptions>`, because the former requires a _more_ specific argument in `SearchAsync`, not a less specific argument. Therefore, a list of `IProductSearchService` does not make sense.

Comment: Hi @RuudvA - thanks for looking at this. I don't understand what you are saying, though :( I'm not saying that your wrong at all - I just don't understand. I thought my *derived* class `HotelProductSearchService1` as two generics which both are derived. So therefore, if both are derived, then both should be auto castable to their base? I'm so confused. Any code to help?

Comment: Everyone else has already mention about covariance etc. If you need to convert between two types of lists, a quick and dirty way is to use "productServices.Cast<HotelServices>()" <-- returns an "IEnumerable<HotelServices>() can throw invalid cast exception but shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments are fare too limited, I'll post this in an answer. It might not solve your problem, but I hope it gives you insight into why your code does not compile. Let's say that you have the following structure:

```
class Animal
{
  public void Eat();
}

class Cow : Animal
{
  public void Moo();
}
```

Cow is [more specific](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) than Animal. That means that everywhere where an Animal is expected, you can also plug in a Cow. However, when a Cow is expected, you cannot plug in an Animal, because an Animal might not be a Cow, and does not know how to Moo.

## What is covariance?

Without variance, the types `IEnumerable<Animal>` and `IEnumerable<Cow>` are not related in any way, but it turns out they are: where an `IEnumerable<Animal>` is expected, we can also plug in an `IEnumerable<Cow>`. Why is that? Because the only thing we can do with `IEnumerable<Animal>`, is extract Animals from it. That is the reason the syntax for covariance is `out`, Animals are only returned by `IEnumerable<Animal>`. We just concluded that we should be able to use a Cow instead of an Animal everywhere, so it would be okay if the enumerable returned Cows. In this sense, we expect `IEnumerable<Cow>` to be derived from `IEnumerable<Animal>`: we should be able to plug in an `IEnumerable<Cow>` where an `IEnumerable<Animal>` is required. This is what covariance does.

## What is contravariance?

Similarly, without variance, the types `Action<Animal>` and `Action<Cow>` are not related. As before, it turns out that they are, because a method that takes an Animal can also be given a Cow. The other way around, a method that takes a Cow cannot be given an Animal in general, so in this case, the relation is the other way around: `Action<Animal>` should be a subtype of `Action<Cow>`, because a method that takes an Animal is also a method that takes a Cow, but a method that takes a Cow is not a method that takes an Animal: it might want to call Moo on the Cow, and that is not possible for an Animal. The syntax for contravariance is `in`, because contravariant types are used as arguments; they cannot be returned.

First, consider a simpler version of `IProductSearchService` with correct variance:

```
public interface IProductSearchService<out TProduct, in TSearchOptions>
  where TProduct : IProduct
  where TSearchOptions : ISearchOptions
{
  TProduct SearchAsync(TSearchOptions searchOptions);
}
```

It is clear that `TProduct` should be covariant, because it is returned.
This means that an `IProductSearchService<HotelProduct, T>` is an `IProductSearchService<IProduct, T>`, but not the other way around.
Therefore, `IEnumerable<IProductSearchService<HotelProduct, T>>` is an `IEnumerable<IProductSearchService<IProduct, T>>`, but not the other way around.

`TSearchOptions` is contravariant, because it is an argument.
This means that `IProductSearchService<T, ISearchOptions>` is an `IProductSearchService<T, HotelSearchOptions>`, but not the other way around.
Therefore, `IEnumerable<IProductSearchService<T, ISearchOptions>>` is an `IEnumerable<IProductSearchService<T, HotelSearchOptions>>`, but not the other way around.
We can enumerate the former, and call `SearchAsync` on the result with `HotelSearchOptions`. But if we enumerate the latter, `SearchAsync` expects `HotelSearchOptions`, so you cannot plug in `ISearchOptions`.

As you can see, these types of variance are incompatible, it is possible to assign `IEnumerable<IProductSearchService<HotelProduct, ISearchOptions>>` to `IEnumerable<IProductSearchService<IProduct, HotelSearchOptions>>`, but it makes no sense the other way around.

## Nested covariance

How can the `out` parameter of `IProductSearchService` be fixed? You must ensure that all the nested generics are covariant. Variance is supported only on interfaces, so you must replace `ProductResult` with an `IProductResult`. Also, `Task` is not covariant (because it is a class), so you cannot use `Task`. [`IObservable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377.aspx) offers similar functionality, and this interface *is* covariant.

```
public interface IProductResult<out T> where T : IProduct { ... }

public interface IProductSearchService<out TProduct, in TSearchOptions>
  where TProduct : IProduct
  where TSearchOptions : ISearchOptions
{
  IObservable<IProductResult<TProduct>> SearchAsync(TSearchOptions searchOptions);
}
```

Comment: oh WoW! An awesome answer I can really grok! OK - this -really- helps me understand the difference now. Phew! Thank you. So I tried what you said .. and I still get a compile time error. Error screenie: http://i.imgur.com/NQF9vkq.png  :~~(

Comment: That is because `T` in `IList<T>` is not covariant. `IList<Cow>` is not an `IList<Animal>`, because calling `Add` with an Animal on `IList<Cow>` is not possible. You will have to use `IEnumerable`. Also, the property will have to be get-only. This is again because `out` types can only be returned. You can still have a setter in an implementation of the interface.

Comment: I don't get the last bit that doesn't work. Trying to add 2x hotels + 1x flight service to a collection. The collection is a list of `List<IProductSearchService<IProduct, ISearchOptions>>` which to me is a `List<Animal>` so .. therefore .. I should be able to add a Hotel (ie a Cow) or a Flight (ie a Dog) to that collection. The collection (to me) is just saying: i want to hold anything that *at least* an `IAnimal`. `Cows` and `Dogs` are both `IAnimals` so that can go into that same bucket / collection... (cont)..

Comment: (..cont) Of course, the only thing we have in common, is `Eat()` unless you specifically cast it. But that's not compiling :( So I guess I don't get it still :( Help?

Comment: No, `IProductSearchService<IProduct, HotelSearchOptions>` is _not_ an `IProductSearchService<IProduct, ISearchOptions>`: you cannot pass it every `ISearchOption` in `SearchAsync`, it must be a subtype of `HotelSearchOptions`, whereas `ISearchOptions` is a supertype.

Comment: Ok - got it working ... sorta :) I'm now stuck trying to create a concrete class that implements this `IProductSearchService`. Remember how you said I can't return a `Task<...>` because that's a class and I need an interface, so you said to use an `IObservable<..>` ? I'm .. er .. trying to create an async method to implement `SearchAsync` .. but I have no idea how :( Urgh :( my head hurts...

Comment: If you don’t want to deal with Rx, you can just [convert between tasks and observables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.threading.tasks.taskobservableextensions_methods%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). Although the `IObservable` interface is in `System`, you do need the [Rx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rx-Main/) assemblies to use it effectively.